# Is the authentication of permissions get wrong?

Tags: database, cnosdb

When creating a regular user and granting admin privileges, the regular user does not have the expected admin privileges

```
public ❯ CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS test WITH PASSWORD='123456', MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD=false, COMMENT = 'test';    
public ❯ alter user test set granted_admin = true;
public ❯ SELECT * FROM cluster_schema.users;
+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_name | is_admin | user_options                                                                                    |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root      | true     | {"password":"*****","must_change_password":true,"comment":"system admin","granted_admin":false} |
| test      | true     | {"password":"*****","must_change_password":false,"comment":"test","granted_admin":true}        |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Query took 0.002 seconds.


[root@cnosdb-01 /]# cnosdb-cli -P 8902 -u test -p 123456
CnosDB CLI v2.3.1
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "test", password: Some("123456"), private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [] }
public ❯ show databases;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010016","error_message":"Auth error: The member test of tenant cnosdb not found"}
```

it's expected that the output should be

```
root@cnosdb-01 /]# cnosdb-cli -P 8902 -u test -p 123456
CnosDB CLI v2.3.1
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "test", password: Some("123456"), private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [] }
public ❯ show databases;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010016","error_message":"Auth error: The member test of tenant cnosdb not found"}
```